# What is this hopping insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

What species is this jumping insect?

Found in the United Kingdom in summer.

About 1 cm body length + 1 cm feelers.

[image: Insect photo]

Comment: The well-developed jumping legs indicate Orthoptera. The undeveloped wings show that it is an immature. The long antennae say Tettigoniidae. I don't know the species.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to be a bush cricket of the *Leptophyes* genus.  Possibly ***Leptophyes punctatissima***, also known as the speckled bush cricket - not sure if the one in your image is speckled or not.  It is endemic to Europe and [can be found in the UK](https://species.nbnatlas.org/species/NBNSYS0000006825#).

[image]

Photo source: [Wikimedia commons - *Leptophyes_punctatissima*](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Leptophyes_punctatissima#/media/File:Leptophyes_punctatissima_(3809033017).jpg)

Comment: Where should I find the speckes if there are any? Are they those orange spots on the back on your photo?

Comment: Oh, it's probably all these little dots on the body! I didn't notice them at first.